# Problema al generar archivo excel

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, apache-poi, librería

Hola el problema es que estoy usando `javafx` en netbeans y use la librería `apache POI` para generar unos archivos excel.

El problema es que cuando uso netbeans genera los archivos correctamente pero cuando lo empaqueto y lo instalo en otra maquina no los genera siento que es un problema de las librerías que no se incluyen pero me aseguro de seleccionar la carpetas **dist** y **src** no se que mas hacer me tiene loco este problema.

Le valide que si ocurría algún error me saltara una pantalla de *`error no se pudo completar`* o *`Correcto`* si era exitoso pero no pasa ninguno

[image: Estas son las librerías que uso creo que todo esta en orden con eso]

**EDITO**

Si lo ejecuto por el CMD me aparece este error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject

Comment: Te aseguraste que la carpeta dist tenga dentro la carpeta de lib?
y el jar lo estas ejecutando en el mismo directorio de la carpeta lib?
ejecutalo desde CMD, hay te pondra el error para que lo compartas.

Comment: Ok ya lo hice edito la pregunta para compartir el error

Answer (score 1):

Es claro que no encuentra la librería, por defecto busca las librerias en el mismo directorio donde estas ejecutando el Jar, si estas seguro que la carpeta lib ya esta en ese lugar y esta contiene la libreria, te recomiendo que generes el JAR con las librerias incluidas, para esto tendras que modificar el archivo build.xml, agrega el siguiente codigo y deberia de compilar con las librerias incluidas en el JAR.

```
<target name="-post-jar">
<property name="store.jar.name" value="AllInOneJar"/>
<property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
<property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
<echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
<jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
<zip destfile="${store.jar}">
    <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
</zip>
<delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te sirve, me pasó lo mismo con hibernate para hacer reportes  en pdf y el problema era que no hayaba la ruta del archivo que hacía de plantilla al estar compilado (en netbeans si). 
Yo no fui capaz de hayar una ruta que funcionara en ambas. Asi que la solución fue copiar el archivo en la carpeta \dist y cambiar la ruta por "Nombre del archivo. Extension" directamente.

```
 String ruta = "c:\\carpeta\\archivo.xsd" ;
 If(ruta.exist()){
//tu código que utiliza la ruta
 } else{
ruta="archivo.xsd";
    //tu código que utiliza la ruta
}
```

Y después simplemente copias la plantilla a la carpeta \dist.
Es una solución regulera, pero me ha funcionado y se ejecuta en el IDE y compilado.

Comment: Disculpa pero no entiendo bien que hiciste en tu caso, la libreria de la plantilla la copiaste en el \dist y que ruta cambiaste?

Comment: He editado la respuesta de arriba.

Answer (score 0):

me paso igual cuando lo jalaba desde cmd me decia que habia una ruta que estaba buscando al generar el excel, era la ruta de una carpeta img donde puse el logo de mi sistema. elimine la carpeta y funciono, o si deceas usar la carpeta simplemente la creas con el mismo dato que le pusiste en netbeans y lo pones donde se genera el dist. y listo

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).